# Authentication over CURL

Tags: posts, errors, authentication, curl

I am working on an API for a WordPress site. Basically, an external application (not made using WP) is able to send JSON to a file I made (`api.php`) and inside that file I load WP (using `wp-load.php`), and create a post (custom post type) based on the received JSON.

When I reach this block of code...

```
$formation_fr = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_type' => 'formation',
    'post_title' => 'example post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 2 // This is an admin account associated with this ID
) );
```

... the post gets created, and everything works except for the `post_author` (instead, there is no author for the post). But, my external application that sent the CURL request will receive this:

```
Error: call to URL http://domain.com/api/api.php failed with status 500, response

Alors, on triche ?
, curl_error , curl_errno 0`
```

The "Alors, on triche?" error is the "Cheatin' uh?" error in French. WordPress for some reason thinks that I'm trying to circumvent capabilities.

If I try to log in the user (ID: 2) programmatically with this block of code...

```
private function login( $id )
{
    $wp_account = get_user_by( 'id', $id );
    $username = $wp_account->data->user_login;
    wp_set_current_user( $wp_account->ID );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $wp_account->ID );
    do_action('wp_login', $username );
}
```

... then I get this:

```
Error: call to URL http://domain.com/api/api.php failed with status 500, response , curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

Which is basically the same error as above but without the "Cheatin' uh?". I didn't expect that to work though, because AFAIK a cookie won't affect a CURL connection.

So, how can I avoid running into capability errors when working over CURL? I've used `wp_insert_post()` many times before and never had this issue. My temporary hacky solution is to erase the `wp_die()` function, which fixes the issue obviously.

WordPress version is 3.9.1

Comment: Ever heard of XML RPC? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself and I'll post it here in case anyone else has this problem. Basically in WP 3.9.1, `wp_insert_post()` checks the current logged in user for account capabilities (at least this is what I assume). Since I was connecting over cURL, there is no logged in user so the capability checks fail. All I had to do was send the cookie WP uses to remember logged in users:

```
$curl = curl_init( 'http://www.domain.com' );
$login_cookie = 'wordpress_logged_in_[hash]=xxx'; // This cookie can be found once a user is logged in.
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $login_cookie );
```

So I simply set up a new admin account for my external application, logged it as that account (using /wp-admin), copied the cookie that WP made for me, and added it to my application.